# SD not detected afte rupgrade

Tags: updates, sd-card

I just updated to Android 6. I am getting a notification that a new SD card is detected. If I format it it will erase everything. It has loads of stuff I want on it. What do I do?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? AFAIK that prompt is suggesting you to "move to [adoptable storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)" (i.e. use the card as "internal storage"). If you decide for that, it in fact will erase all contents on the card. If OTOH you decide to keep the card as "external storage", it should *not* erase anything. Don't take my word on the latter, though, as I was not (yet) able to verify that myself. Please follow the link, compare the screenshot.

Comment: Before doing anything, you should fully backup the card in case any data is lost.

Comment: It was the screen on top i got. But it just started working again after 20-30 mins. cheers lads.

Comment: @Izzy I can confirm that setting the SD as external storage maintains its content untouched.

Comment: Thanks, @DeathMaskSalesman – so I wrote this up as an answer, giving credit to your confirmation :)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your situation with the screenshots in our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info): what's going on here is Marshmallow asking you how to deal with the card (it asks only once). If you chose to use it as "internal storage", indeed all its contents will be deleted (see tag-wiki again for details). But if you chose to keep it as "portable storage" (i.e. the same way it was used before), your data on it will remain intact – as [Death Mask Salesman](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/152843/death-mask-salesman) just confirmed in a comment on the question itself.

Comment: If my info can help, I'm happy to share it, man. For some time, I went with CM13 nightlies, and I selected the "Use as external storage" (or something like that), when the dialog about the SD popped up. The result was that I didn't lose anything.